# How to replace only the files not the same, instead of the whole directory when using data volume container as a share storage for other containers

Tags: docker

Requirement: when an new version of J2EE application go into production, because development environment and production is not the same, the DBA has to replace some configuration file in war package, those files which need to replace typically contains some sensitive data (like database account, password).

I think is a good idea to create a data volume container, which contain those configuration files that specific to production. In this case, configuration files can be share between containers (applications)'

Let say I have and J2EE application run with docker using tomcat 8, the dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM tomcat:8

WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

RUN midair -p /etc/foo

RUN touch /etc/foo/a

RUN touch /etc/foo/b

RUN touch /etc/foo/c

RUN touch /etc/foo/d

RUN echo "a" >> /etc/foo/a

RUN echo "b" >> /etc/foo/b

RUN echo "c" >> /etc/foo/c

RUN echo "d" >> /etc/foo/d

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

The DBA has to replace the file b and c before the application go into production, as a result, we have a dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM centos:6.8

RUN mkdir -p /etc/foo

RUN touch /etc/foo/a

RUN touch /etc/foo/d

RUN echo "sub a" >> /etc/foo/a

RUN echo "sub d" >> /etc/foo/d

COPY ./run.sh /root

RUN chmod 755 /root/run.sh

CMD ["/root/run.sh"]
```

To test whether the data volume container would satisfy my requirement, the following command is run :

```
docker create -v /etc/foo --name configstore centos:6.8 /bin/bash

docker run -d --volumes-from configstore --name testsubcontainer  tomcat:8
```

And finally I found that the “tomcat” container has “a” and “d” in the `/etc/foo` b and c has gone.

Q1: How to replace only the files not the same, instead of the whole directory when using data volume container as a share storage for other containers.

Q2: Is there any other better solution to satisfy my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Using volumes as you are, this is not possible. When you mount a volume to a directory in a container, everything inside that directory is replaced by the data volume. Docker isn't mapping files, it's mounting the volume at a certain point in the container filesystem.

Q2: Have you explored ENV or ARG as a means to set values at runtime?